# Decorate the active tab in R shiny tabPanel: add nice looking border-top

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

As I am learning R shiny, I realize how little I know about css and html, and would appreciate your help. Currently I would like the active tab in tabPanel to show a color "bar" on top. My solution is to use the following style.css

```css
.content-wrapper .tabbable .nav .active {
    border-top: 3px solid red;
}
```

The result looks like:[image]

It is basically what I wanted, except that I would want the red line be shorter, not going outside of the tab itself. I tried to change the length of the border-top but was not successful. Any suggestion please? Thank you very much!

Reproducible code see below:

```
library("shiny")
library("shinydashboard")


ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Title"),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
      tags$head(
        #add css style sheet to shiny dashboard
        tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "style.css")),

      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(title = HTML(paste("Tab A"))),
        tabPanel(title = HTML(paste("Tab B")))
    )))

server = function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```